# Command button doesn't calls it's action method after including prettyfaces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, prettyfaces

I have embedded prettyfaces recently into my webapp and now I have really strange behavior.

I have an update user form with a commandbutton: The commmandbutton look likes following.

Neither command link nor command button invokes action method which is in thee bean.
My bean is a View-Scoped bean.

When I click the button, the page simply reloaded and the action which is defined to be called is not invoked! Simply, just page reload performs.

```
<p:commandButton style=" float: right; margin-left: 10px; " id="saveEditUser" update=":form" value="Save" action="#{editUser.updateUser()}"  ajax="false" />
```

But, when I remove the related lines in prettyfaces, then my page works find. ( following is what I have defined in prettyfaces related to edit user)

```
<url-mapping id="EditUser" onPostback="false">
    <pattern value="/User/Edit/#{initalUserName}" />
    <view-id value="/user/EditUser.xhtml" />
</url-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By bring changes on the pretty faces it works now.

```
<url-mapping id="EditUser" onPostback="false">
    <pattern value="/EditUser/" />
    <view-id value="/user/EditUser.xhtml" />
            <query-param name="initalUserName"> #{editUser.initalUserName} </query-param>
</url-mapping>
```

Note: even when I change  without backslash again same issue happen.

Answer (score 0):

Is the method `editUser.updateUser()` really called after a click on the button? (use a breakpoint to make sure)

My guess is your mapping should be :

```
<url-mapping id="EditUser" onPostback="false">
    <pattern value="/User/Edit/#{initalUserName}" />
    <view-id value="/user/EditUser.jsf" />
</url-mapping>
```

Note the `.xhtml` being replaced by `.jsf`

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Actually the updateUser() isn't call any way, the page jut being refreshed. but I was able to solve the problem with a little changes on mapping.